# Testing data from an AJAX request before rendering the DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have a pretty standard definition for a datatable, and generall it works fine:

```
$('#overview_all').dataTable( {
    "ajax": "./data.php?view_name=vt_all_requests_by_service&system_id="+system_id
} );
```

However, sometimes no data is returned (by design), in which case the resulting "data" object contains only Boolean `False`.
How can I test for this before DataTables renders the table? I want to pre-empt DataTables and stop it from trying to do anything in this circumstance.

I've tried adding a "success" parameter function in there, but that causes the entire request to fail:

```
    $('#overview_all').dataTable( {
    "ajax": {
"url": "./data.php?view_name=vt_all_requests_by_service&system_id="+system_id,
    "success": alert(5)
    }
    } );
```

I'm sure this is something simple with DataTables but can't find any examples.
Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: What happens to the DataTable when no data is returned?

Comment: @Aaron - I never thought of that. It renders *No data available in table* instead, so I've set my data to return that. Nice implied answer. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Do a check whenever datatables makes an ajax call using http://datatables.net/reference/event/xhr

or

- Do a check whenever the table is about to get initialised (this occurs after the ajax call returns). http://datatables.net/reference/option/initComplete

In both cases, the variable you want to test is called 'json' in the docs.

Look under the "Callbacks" section of http://datatables.net/reference/option and you'll see a whole bunch of other callbacks you might be able to use.

Comment: Thanks, the xhr does what I want. In combination with Aarons comment, I set  `json.data = []` which triggered DataTables normal response of "No data for table".

Comment: As a nice hint to users, you can make the "No data for table" message much more user friendly by using http://datatables.net/reference/option/language.emptyTable and setting it to something like "No shopping cart items exist for the selected time".